# Database triggers not working in integration testing

Tags: java, postgresql, docker-compose, integration-testing, database-trigger

I have created database triggers to manage the created and updated timestamps in my Postgres schema for my Spring boot application. When I run my integration tests, I see the created and updated field are not changed by the triggers and are still null. I am running my integration tests using docker-compose. I managing the table versioning & migrations with Flyway. I created the table initially and adding the trigger(mentioned below) later with another migration script. Is there a way to test the trigger functions or anything wrong with my trigger function?

Here is the trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_created_updated_dates()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
  IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
    NEW.created := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    NEW.updated := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
  ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
    NEW.updated := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
  END IF;

  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

routings is the name of my table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER routings_set_created_updated_dates
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON routings
  FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_created_updated_dates();
```

Here is my docker compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mockserver:
    image: "artifactory.random/docker/jamesdbloom/mockserver:mockserver-5.5.1"
    ports:
      - 1080
  database:
    image: postgres:10.5
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=test
      - POSTGRES_USER=test
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test123
    ports:
      - 5432
```

Comment: Are you sure that the INSERT or UPDATE statements are executed? Do you have a transaction in your tests?

Comment: Yes, I am first creating a record as a pre setup step for my test and then the code which is being tested is updating the record.

Comment: But if a UPDATE statement is executed the trigger is called. If the trigger is not called the statement is not executed. Or is a rollback happening anywhere?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli there is no rollback statement. I am doing a record update in the code and then getting the updated values in my test class.

Comment: So I'm sure there is no Update Statement executed. Can you show the code?

Comment: You show too little of your setup for us to be able to determine what's wrong. Perhaps there are several tables with the same name in different schemas or databases, and you are updating the wrong ones. Perhaps you run with `session_replication_role = replica`.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli other values are getting updated for the record.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe there is only 1 table in the schema right now. I do realise it's quite difficult to guess with little information. I have updated the question with more details. Let me know if you need more code or schema information.